# Does Interface java.util.Map overrides hashCode() and equals() from Object class

Tags: java, oop, object, dictionary, inheritance

As per the Java-Doc for [java.util.Map](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html), the `hashCode` and `equals` methods are overridden from the `Object` class. But interfaces do not inherit from the `Object` class, so how does the `Map` interface override the `Object` class' methods?

Comment: Simple answer: it doesn't.

Comment: It provides a specification for concrete implementations, but can't itself override anything, nor can it enforce the specifications.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels not strictly speaking true any more I believe. An `interface` can override a`default` method from a parent `interface`.

Comment: @BoristheSpider: true, but it doesn't provide code for this.

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels The claim that interfaces can't override anything is only application to java 7 and older. In Java 8 that is possible with default methods.

Comment: @AminJ: true, but this interface to be backwards compatable will not override the methods

Comment: @AminJ not strictly speaking true either. An `interface` can only override behavior from a parent `interface`. And the original behaviour can always be invoked from an inheriting `class` - this differs from overriding in a number of ways.

Comment: @BoristheSpider I believe it is explicitly disallowed to skip a default implementation to invoke "the original" default implementation of a super super interface. [JLS §15.12.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.1): *[...] It is a compile-time error if `I` is not a **direct superinterface** of `T` [...]*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `@Override` annotation has special consideration for methods inherited from `Object`:

Quoting Java Language Specification, [§9.6.4.4 @Override](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.6.4.4):

> If a method declaration is annotated with the annotation `@Override`, but the method does not override or implement a method declared in a supertype, **or is not override-equivalent to a `public` method of `Object`**, a compile-time error occurs.

This means that `@Override` can annotate interface methods that will be inherited from `Object` in the implementing class, even though the interface itself is not inheriting from `Object`.

It is used as a safeguard against accidentally declaring an interface method that clashes with `Object` methods.

Answer (score 1):

The Javadoc means that each implementing class should override the methods to achieve the behavior that is documented in Javadoc.

Comment: `s/has to/should/g`.

Comment: That again doesn't makes much of a sense, as Object class is being inherited by all the classes in java, so why we have to mention hashcode and equals methods separately in Map interface.

Comment: The point is not that the methods exist, but instead what they do.

Answer (score 0):

Thats because interfaces cannot be instanciated as interfaces. You use it as an interface but the JVM is referencing an Object instance implementing the interface, so as an Object it has toString, hashCode and equals. (even if they don't work as you expect if you don't override them in the implementation class)